# Add .old to files without .old in them, having trouble with which variable to use?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, ls

```
#!/bin/bash
for filenames in $( ls $1 )
 do
  echo $filenames | grep "\.old$"
   if [ ! $filenames  = 0 ]
    then
     $( mv "$1/$filenames" "$1/$filenames.old" )
   fi
done
```

So I think most of the script works. It is intended to take the output of ls for a directory inputed in the first parameter, and search for any files with .old at the end. Any files that do not contain .old will then be renamed. 
The script successfully renames the files, but it will add .old to a file already containing the extension. I am assuming that the if variable is wrong, but I cannot figure out which variable to use in this case.

Answer is in the key but if anyone needs to do this here is an even easier way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filenames in $( ls $1 | grep -v "\.old$" )
do
     $( mv "$1/$filenames" "$1/$filenames.old" )
done
```

Comment: you don't need the `$( ... )` surrounding your `mv` cmd. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find for this

```
find /directory/here -type f ! -iname "*.old" -exec mv {} {}.old \;
```

**Problems the original approach**

- `for filenames in $( ls $1 )` Never parse `ls` output. Check [[ this ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- Variables are not double quoted, say in `if [ ! $filenames  = 0 ]`. This results in word-splitting. Use `"$filenames"` unless you expect word splitting.

---

So the final script would be

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$1" ]
then
 find "$1" -type f ! -iname "*.old" -exec mv {} {}.old \;
 # use -maxdepth 1 with find if  you don't wish to recursively check subdirectories
else
 echo "Directory : $1 doesn't exist !"
fi
```

**Usage**

```
./script '/path/to/directory'
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't need to be so complex. I simply needed to tell the script "If the output of grep is not true then rename the file to make it true".

Comment: @KieranO'Connor: Using `grep` or `ls` like your example is a recipe for disaster; use a glob or for loop instead. Too many bad things can start to happen when doing unnecessary things.

Comment: `find` will visit subdirectories, too (unless you specifically keep it out) which is probably wrong for this task.

Comment: @tripleee : Right ! I have put a comment regarding `-maxdepth 1` with find.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "$1"/*
do
  case $filename in *.old) continue;; esac
  mv "$filename" "$filename.old"
done
```

I prefer `case` over `if` because it supports wildcard matching naturally and portably.  (You could run this with `/bin/sh` just as well.)  If you wanted to use `if` instead, that'd be

```
if echo "$filename" | grep -q '\.old$'; then
```

or more idiomatically, but recent shells only,

```
if [[ "$filename" == *.old ]]; then
```

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it does work but my homework assignment required me to use ls in the for loop. I've done some more research on why you wouldn't want to use it, and I agree in 99% of cases. My shell only outputs filenames, and only 1 per line if there is no -l argument, so there is no issue with using this script in a subdirectory that only contains files or directories you no longer use.

Comment: There *is* a `for` loop.  The first problem with `ls` is that if its output contains a space, the shell will split it into two tokens like `the: file not found` and `file: file not found`.  The next problem is that if there are adjacent spaces, the shell will basically ignore them, as if there was only one. And of course, the [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) is just wasteful. If your lecturer insists on using an external subprocess where none is necessary, they are incompetent, and you are welcome to ask them to register here to discuss further.

Comment: ... or preparing to reveal the shocking truth to you in the next lecture.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid calling additional *utility* functions if simple shell builtins will do. Why? Each additional utility you call `grep`, etc. spawns and runs in a separate subshell of its own. (if you are spawning a subshell for *every* iteration in your loop -- things will really slow down) If the shell doesn't provide a feature, then sure... calling a utility is the right thing to do.

As mentioned above, shell globbing along with *parameter expansion* with *substring removal* provides a simple test for determining if a file has an `.old` extension. All you need is:

```
for i in "$1"/*; do
    [ "${i##*.}" = "old" ] || mv "$i" "${i}.old"
done
```

(**note:** this will skip add the `.old` extension to single file named `'old'`, but that can be handled separately if needed -- unlikely. Additionally, the solution with `find` is a fine approach as well)

Comment: I guess you want `mv` instead of `move`.

Answer (score -3):

I solved the problem, as I was misled by my instructor!
$? is the variable which represents the pipeline output which is currently in the forground (which would be grep). The new code is unedited except for

```
if [ ! $? = 0 ]
```

Comment: Use `-eq` for integer comparison.

Comment: I'm aware of -eq but I think my schools matrix uses either = or -eq.

Comment: try `echo '$? now = '$? ; true ; echo '$?=' $? ; false ; echo '$?=' $? ; true ; echo '$?='$?` . You should see 0,0,1,0 (on separate lines). This is the return code from the previous command that has been executed, not "the variable which represents the pipeline output which is currently in the forground " . Good luck

Comment: You should almost never need to examine `$?` directly.  All the shell's built-in conditional control flow statements do this behind the scenes; `while` and `if` run a command, and examine its exit code.

Comment: You need to throw away your old code as it is riddled with problems and adopt one of the solutions posted here.